# Partitioning a List using a List

Tags: applescript, partition, sorting

I'm working on a project which requires me to partition a list using a list. I've created a solution which works in some situations, but not every situation. Is anyone able to help me with the logic?

There's two lists. The sum of each list will always be equal. The first list (i.e. the partitionBy list) is used to partition the second list (i.e the inputList).

Here's a simplified example:

List A {3, 2, 4}
List B {2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1}

The first item of List A is 3. The sum of the first and second items of List B = 3 (i.e 2 + 1). Create a list for those items

The second item of List A is 2. The sum of the third and fourth items of List B = 2 (i.e. 1 + 1). Create a list for those items

etc ...

Ideal result would be: {{2, 1}, {1, 1}, {3, 1}}

The code is currently in AppleScript, but I'd be happy to translate it to JavaScript, if that helps.

Here's the code w/ examples:

```
--Example 1 works as expected
set partitionBy1 to {4, 1, 9, 6, 2, 2} -- list to partition by
set inputList1 to   {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1} -- list to partition

-- required output: {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1}, {2, 2, 2, 3}, {3, 3}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}
-- actual output:   {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1}, {2, 2, 2, 3}, {3, 3}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}

--Example 2 works as expected
set partitionBy2 to {4, 2, 8, 6, 2, 2}
set inputList2 to   {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1}

-- required output: {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {3, 3}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}
-- actual output:   {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {3, 3}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}

--Example 3 does not work as expected
set partitionBy3 to {4, 1, 9, 1, 3, 6, 2, 2}
set inputList3 to   {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1}

-- required output: {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1}, {2, 2, 2, 3}, {1}, {3}, {3, 3}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}
-- actual output:   {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1}, {2, 2, 2, 3}, {3}, {3}, {3, 3}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}


partitionList(inputList3, partitionBy3)

on partitionList(inputList, partitionBy)
    set partitionedList to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to (count partitionBy)
        set partitionNumber to item i of partitionBy
        set runningTotal to 0
        set intermediateList to {}
        repeat with j from 1 to ((count inputList) - 1)
            set inputNumber to item j of inputList
            set runningTotal to runningTotal + inputNumber
            if runningTotal = partitionNumber then
                set end of partitionedList to (intermediateList & inputNumber)
                set inputList to items (j + 1) thru -1 of inputList
                exit repeat
            else if runningTotal > partitionNumber then
                set item j of inputList to (inputNumber - 1)
                set inputList to (inputNumber - 1) & inputList
                set end of partitionedList to (intermediateList & (inputNumber - 1))
                set inputList to items (j + 1) thru -1 of inputList
                exit repeat
            else
                set end of intermediateList to inputNumber
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
    set end of partitionedList to intermediateList & item -1 of inputList
    return partitionedList
end partitionList
```

Comment: Partition is used as a verb in this context. It means to divide into parts.

Comment: It would help if you described the partition scheme.

Comment: It's unclear what is supposed to happen if the element(s) can't be added to the requested sum (which occurs in the non-working example).

Comment: I suppose it could create an error message, but ideally, the function would be able to determine how to organize the second list by the first list, as the sum of each list will always be the same. This is probably more of a math question than a coding question, which is probably why I'm having difficulty with it :)

Comment: The simplified example is helpful, I suppose, but you really have to explain ***in words*** what your partitioning system is.  It looks from the simplified example as though you want something like "find sequential pairs of numbers in the input list that add up to each consecutive number in the partition list", but that doesn't jive with examples 2 and 3 (e.g., there is no sequence '1,2,2,3' in inputList2; no obvious system to get to your 'required' output). I don't have the time or inclination to reverse engineer your code to see what you're after, so you have to be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the linear incrementation of `j`.

In case of `runningTotal > partitionNumber` you have to assign the difference (or the remainder) to `inputNumber` and evaluate the next partition without incrementing `j`.

I replaced `repeat with` with `repeat while`, added an `overflow` variable to indicate that `runningTotal` is greater than `partitionNumber` and declared `j` as local variable to have full control.

```
on partitionList(inputList, partitionBy)
    set partitionedList to {}
    set j to 1
    set overflow to false
    repeat with i from 1 to (count partitionBy)
        set partitionNumber to item i of partitionBy
        set runningTotal to 0
        set intermediateList to {}
        repeat while j < (count inputList)
            if overflow then
                set overflow to false
            else
                set inputNumber to item j of inputList
            end if
            set runningTotal to runningTotal + inputNumber
            if runningTotal = partitionNumber then
                set end of partitionedList to (intermediateList & inputNumber)
                set j to j + 1
                exit repeat
            else if runningTotal > partitionNumber then
                set end of partitionedList to {partitionNumber}
                set overflow to true
                set inputNumber to runningTotal - partitionNumber
                exit repeat
            else
                set end of intermediateList to inputNumber
                set j to j + 1
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
    set end of partitionedList to intermediateList & item -1 of inputList
    return partitionedList
end partitionList
```

Comment: Thank you very much, vadian! I sincerely appreciate the solution and explanation.